# Building is half "Reflective"

Tags: texturing

I am hoping some of you clever people can help! I am a complete novice at Blender but It's been fun and frustrating learning it!
Anyway I have made a few buildings for my local Airport for MSFS and one building is sort of half reflective like a mirror this is the only building I have had bother with (used same settings as the rest of the others and specular is turned down[image]) and I just can't suss it out.
In blender and ModelconvertorX it looks fine.
Any help is appreciated. [image]

Comment: It appears to actually not be reflective, but just transparent. Is it possible that a texture somewhere is being mapped onto the wrong material? Double check all your blender materials and see that nothing is connected to any kind of transparency setting on the shader. In EEVEE, materials will render opaque unless you have their blend setting changed to something else, even if something is connected to the transparency of the shader. I’m thinking that something is connected erroneously, but it’s not showing up in blender because the blend setting of the material is set to the default “opaque.”

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I say I am an a novice at this and tried your advice and I am probably doing it wrong but I am stumped!